# Import Theora video into Premiere Elements

Tags: premiere, windows, premiere-elements

I am trying to edit a Theora video in Premiere Elements 10. I installed the Xiph OpenCodecs package which allowed me to view the video in WMP, but it still wouldn't import into PRE. I then tried installing QuickTime and the XiphQT package, but still no joy. However, QT wouldn't play the video so maybe this didn't work. I notice that the Xiph website has not been updated since 2009, so maybe these are out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it [doesn't appear possible](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4817383) to directly import Ogg Theora video into Premiere Elements 10, however I did manage to convert the video to DNxHD/VC-3 so that PRE would handle it nicely (previous conversions had [behaved very badly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDx3krqie9E))

```
ffmpeg -i out-48.ogv -s 1920x1080 -r pal -b 36M -threads 2 -vcodec dnxhd -acodec libmp3lame out-48.mov
```

http://blog.jamiek.it/2012/11/encoding-ogv-files-to-edit-in-adobe.html